# xmlhttp and PHP not working?

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

So I've been learning to use xmlhttp and I couldn't get this simple script working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script>
            function print_stuff(){
                document.getElementById("two").innerHTML="working";
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else{// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("one").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                  }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("POST","index.php",true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");   
                xmlhttp.send("email=" + document.getElementByName("email").value + "&name="+ document.getElementByName("name").value);
            }
        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">    
    </head>
    <body>
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></br>
            Email:<input type="text" name="email"/></br>
            <button onclick="print_stuff()">Button</button></br>
        <span id="one"></span>
        <div id="two"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the index.php:

```
    <?php 
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    echo "Name: ",$name,"</br> Email: ", $email;
    ?>
```

The idea behind this is very simple: you get user's name and email and print it out using "POST" method. I have a sense it's a very simple mistake, though I can't find it... Any help appreciated!

Comment: Which part isn't working? You seem to have all the parts in order.

Comment: Well the innerHTML of <span id="one"/> doesn't change. I mean, it should be a problem with either xmlhttp or PHP script I guess...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">    
    </head>
    <body>
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/></br>
            Email:<input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></br>
            <button onclick="print_stuff()">Button</button></br>
        <span id="one"></span>
        <div id="two"></div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    function print_stuff(){

       var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
       var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

       if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            { 
                array = new Array(4);
                array = xmlhttp.responseText.split("##"); //slicing string into array to get separate result

                document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = array.slice(0,1);
                document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = array.slice(1,2);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?email="+email+"&name="+name,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php 
    $name = "Name: ".$_GET["name"];
    $email = "Email: ".$_GET["email"];

    echo $name."##".$email;
?>
```

Comment: This seems OK to me, not sure why it had a downvote. (Please leave a comment if you downvote so _we_ know what's wrong).